# how to pass an array from one class controller to another in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I have two Controller such as doc.php, user.php in controller folder and a registration.php in a view folder, which have a registration form.
i want to **pass the registration info** from registration.php to doc.php controller via user.php.
How can i do this? Need help.

Comment: use **session** or store them in **DB**. You can call another controller inside the controller.

Comment: is there any way to pass it directly without using session or saving anywhere?

Comment: If you must call one controller from another, you can instantiate the second controller from the first and pass the array as an argument?

Comment: You might be best to look at HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc

Comment: example or any details? @Magnus Eriksson

Comment: This question belongs to `Codeigniter` or `Laravel` ?

Comment: CodeIgniter 3.0.3 @SulthanAllaudeen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your codeigniter version ? 2.x or 3.x ?

Try to use session to save your array.

To initialize the Session class manually in your controller constructor, use this  method:

```
$this->load->library();
```

Once loaded, the Sessions library object will be available using:

```
$this->session
```

You can set you session name, using this code :

```
$this->session->your_session_name;
```

Use this to add an item in your session :

```
$this->session->your_session_name('item_one');
```

To retrieve your session, use this code :

```
$this->session->your_session_name;
```

[Check this](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) for CodeIgniter 3.X

[Check this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) for CodeIgniter 2.X

Answer (score 1):

In CodeIgnitor you typically use the session object to pass data between controllers. For example:

```
// initialise the session object
$this->load->library('session');

// save the array to the session
$this->session->set_userdata('reg_info', $reg_info);

// retrieve the array in the other controller:
$this->session->userdata('reg_info');
```

More info on CodeIgnitor's session object can be found in the [docs](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html).